# Is the any comparability issue with nuxt Auth Module and vuex-persist?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex, nuxt.js

Is there any compatible issue with [nuxt Auth module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) and [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) ?

I was added vuex-persist like this.

```
// Inside - nuxt.config.js
export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist', ssr: false }
  ]
}

// ~/plugins/vuex-persist.js
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'

export default ({ store }) => {
  window.onNuxtReady(() => {
    new VuexPersistence({
    /* your options */
    }).plugin(store);
  });
}
```

But it fails to work.

1. When i click login it perform previous action(login with
   google/other previously clicked).
2. When logged in the status fails to persists.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there was some issues with `@nuxtjs/auth` module and `vuex-persist` ,

**use this**

```
// ~/store/index.js
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'
const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
  storage: window.localStorage
})

export const plugins = [vuexLocal.plugin]
```

**instead of this in the documentation**

```
// Inside - nuxt.config.js
export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist', ssr: false }
  ]
}
```

```
// ~/plugins/vuex-persist.js
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'

export default ({ store }) => {
  window.onNuxtReady(() => {
    new VuexPersistence({
    /* your options */
    }).plugin(store);
  });
}
```

or you can use [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) as an alternative.

Comment: Is there a way to work with multiTabState?